# NSSpellChecker certain language not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, spell-checking

My mac version is 10.13.4 with xcode version 9.4.1

I'm trying to use NSSpellChecker with Korean language. But regardless of whether the word I check is misspelled or not, the Range returned is {2^63 - 1, 0}

Based on quick experiments with english, that Range is returned when there are no misspelled words OR if the input word language doesn't match current spell checker's language.

This is what I'm doing:

```
NSSpellChecker *checker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];
NSString *sampleWord = @"마직막";
NSRange range = [checker checkSpellingOfString:sampleWord, startingAt: 0];
NSLog(@"range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
```

that sampleWord is misspelled, but I'm getting

```
range: {9223372036854775807, 0}
```

as the output.

Could someone provide any insight on what's happening?

Edit1: When I throw correct english words at it, NSSpellChecker indicates spelling error, which is correct. I gave an english word to korean environment. So I guess NSSpellChecker itself is working correctly, but there is something I missed regarding setup kind of..?

Comment: Hi, yes it's returning not found: `if (range.location == NSNotFound) { ...` Perhaps setting the language might be of interest https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspellchecker/1532988-setlanguage?language=objc

Comment: the language is set to @"ko". That's part of why I'm confused. The language is set to Korean, but spell checking isn't working..

Comment: FWIW there is a comma following on ```sampleWord``` when you calculate the range.

Comment: oh that's just a typo here. No comma in my code.

Comment: Does TextEdit detect "마직막"? Have you tried other misspelled words? Do you set the language of the spell checker or is the language set in System Prefs? Have you tried without `automaticallyIdentifiesLanguages`?

Comment: TextEdit does not detect "마직막", but it did detect other misspelled words such as "맠아리라". I set the language of spell checker, and I called [checker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:false] to disable automatic language detection.
Actually, spell checker started to work, but inconsistently. I get different answers for same input. "마직막" fails sometime, and passes sometimes.... It works kind of, and I'm more confused...

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes not ... that is difficult to fix ... maybe show how you handle the locale as well. Do you e.g. set the locale yourself or pick it up from the system or really do you do anything there that could cause this instability?

Comment: One thing that I'm suspecting is I get the word input from console, and I use scanf to receive the input. So maybe there are problems with stdin buffers or the cstring array itself..? I'm calling fflush(stdin) at the end of every iteration so I'm not sure how possible that is, but I will be looking for another way to accept input

Comment: I call [checker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages: false] and [checker setLanguages:@"ko"] to set the language to use

Comment: I've tried and get same result as you ... will post my code shortly but if possible give me a few more misspelled Korean words - I am helpless there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code I used, based on your code and comments.

```
        // insert code here...
        NSSpellChecker *checker = [NSSpellChecker sharedSpellChecker];

        // NSLog ( @"Available %@", checker.availableLanguages );
        NSLog ( @"Korean %@", [checker.availableLanguages containsObject:@"ko"] ? @"YES" : @"NO" ); // Prints YES

        [checker setAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages:NO]; // Seems to have NO impact
        NSLog ( @"KO %@", [checker setLanguage:@"ko"] ? @"YES" : @"NO" ); // Prints YES
    
        // NSString * sampleWord = @"마직막 마직막 마직막 마직막 마직막"; // makes no difference
        NSString * sampleWord = @"마직막"; // makes no difference
        // NSString * sampleWord = @"마직막 ddd sss aaa"; // consistently prints { 4, 3 }
        // NSString * sampleWord = @"안녕하세요 햇살 가득한 남아프리카에서 왔습니다. 마직막 안녕하세요 햇살 가득한 남아프리카에서 왔습니다."; // all fine for this one also
        // NSString * sampleWord = @"안녕하세요 햇살 가녕하세득한 남녕하세아프리카에서 왔습니다. 마직막 안녕하세요 햇녕하세살 가득한 남아프리카에서 왔습니다."; // here I finally start to see some result { 45, 5 }

        NSRange range = [checker checkSpellingOfString:sampleWord
                            startingAt:0];
        NSLog(@"range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range)); // Consistently prints { NSNotFound, 0 }

        NSInteger wc;

        // Since you force the language I think this
        // is better way of checking
        range = [checker checkSpellingOfString:sampleWord
                       startingAt:0
                         language:@"ko"
                         wrap:NO
                   inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
                         wordCount:& wc];

        NSLog(@"spelling range: %@ wc %lu", NSStringFromRange(range), wc); // Consistently prints { NSNotFound, 0 } wc 1

        range = [checker checkGrammarOfString:sampleWord
                       startingAt:0
                         language:@"ko"
                         wrap:NO
                   inSpellDocumentWithTag:0
                          details:nil];

        NSLog(@"grammer range: %@ wc %lu", NSStringFromRange(range), wc); // Consistently prints { NSNotFound, 0 } wc 1
```

The word you are testing with *마직막* appears to be valid and passes consistently - even in the grammar test.

If I create some kind of a sentence and mess it up by randomly pasting in letters then I start getting some sensible (and consistent) feedback from the spell checker. See the code for more info.

Mostly I think you should use, as shown in the code, the message that allows you to specify the language rather than the one that does not since you are forcing the language. But I do not see inconsistency here. If I paste the word into Notes it also does not highlight it, although my intentionally erroneous string does light up there as well.

**EDIT**

I've played with your code a bit. Note that `readline` will append the newline so I changed the code by trimming all white space and newlines from `theWord` as below.

```
NSString *sampleWord = [[NSString stringWithCString:theWord encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

Initially I got the discrepancy you mention but just as I got excited it disappeared. So yes, it seems inconsistent. I am not sure if the spell checker got smarter or if the console got better at dealing with the input.

The basic problem, I believe, is that `getline` reads `char`s. So I also tried e.g.

```
            NSString *sampleWord = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:theWord
                                           length:len_read
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     freeWhenDone:YES] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
```

but got the same result. Here I also tried

```
NSASCIIStringEncoding
```

and

```
NSUTF16StringEncoding
```

but only

```
NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

worked correctly, so it seems the console returns UTF8 strings. At least for me, I suspect this will be different based on the locale and other settings.

**Discrepancy**

So what about that. Yesterday when I ran my code, for the very first time, I think it produced a spelling error. Never again. I ran it a lot but never again and I am not even sure it really did produce that error anymore. Same today. I ran your code and the first time it marked the word as an error, but never again. By now, after running it again many times, I am starting to wonder if I was not mistaken as I simply can not generate it again.

Maybe the spell checker takes a while to initialise and this gives rise to the discrepancy. I could not find anything in the manual that points to this. Maybe the console gets smart as I enter Hangul and this is why it generates two separate outputs. Maybe the clipboard sees I am copy and pasting Hangul and changes something somewhere.

The strange thing though is that I repeated the whole thing on my MacBook as well, hoping to get the failure / misspelt word the first time again and this time copying the log out. But there it just worked from the first time.

Maybe run your code a few times and see if it stabilises after a while. Here it seems that (maybe) the first time it marks the word as misspelt but never again, so I am as perplexed as you are at present.

**Follow up**

Note that I am unable to get the spellchecker to mark the word as misspelt. I also tried the other words you gave and later even some gibberish but the spell checker never flagged anything as incorrect.

Then I tried on my Mac again and this time everything I tried was marked (correctly) as incorrect. So the result is not consistent between my Mac and Macbook, although, where it works, it seems that "마직막" is spelt correctly according to Apple.

I can not explain this but suspect it has to do with language and locale setting differences between the two machines, even though the code is the same and there are no differences I am aware of. On both machines the output is the same, notably it outputs `YES` when I initialise the Korean dictionary.

Comment: Some other misspelled words are "맠아리라", "밐쿠", "안녛하세오", "할압버지", "우리갖족".

Comment: Right now, what I'm seeing right now is that "마직막" is not being passed as a valid string.
I'll post my code, and results below

Comment: First I want to say a really big thanks for all the efforts you have put into helping me. It must've taken you a long time to do all this, and I really appreciate it.
Not to throw you more problems, but there are more discrepancies between running the program from Xcode vs terminal on my macbook. Specifically, "마지막ㄱ" is marked(correctly) as incorrect in Xcode, but is marked(incorrectly) as correct when I run the program in iTerm2.
So now, I kinda gave up using NSSpellChecker tbh, and decided to find another way. I'll probably be trying to figure this out, but just for the fun of it I guess.

Comment: I was able to find something called hunspell, and I'll see if I can use that instead. But again, thank you so very much for the help, I really really appreciate it!!

Comment: Thank you as well - I appreciate your feedback. I note your concern but I'd keep on using it. I think the console is not a realistic scenario (unless you are going to use it that way) and think if you hook it up to some text field it will probably work (better). Also, here we are using just a single word or sentence. I think for a whole document it will perhaps perform better. I saw hunspell as well in the frameworks. Good luck with that and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I'm using right now, where "마직막" is failing.

```
while(true) {
    char *theWord = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    printf("ENTER A WORD\n");
    size_t len_read = getline(&theWord, &len, stdin);
    printf("%s\n", theWord);
    
    NSString *sampleWord = [NSString stringWithCString:theWord encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSInteger wc;
    
    NSRange range = [checker checkSpellingOfString:sampleWord startingAt:0 language:@"ko" wrap:NO inSpellDocumentWithTag:0 wordCount:&wc];
    
    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
        printf("Correct Spelling\n");
    } else {
        printf("Bad Spelling. Incorrect Spelling at\n");
        NSLog(@"The range: %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    free(theWord);
}
```

And if I input "마직막", this is what I'm getting.

ENTER A WORD
마직막
ㅁㅏㅈㅣㄱㅁㅏㄱ

Bad Spelling. Incorrect Spelling at
2020-11-27 10:39:23.916315+0900 spellCheckTest[6410:124279] The range: {0, 8}

So we're getting different results using the same input. Could this be because of how I'm accepting input from console??